# cannot assign to `self.b` because it is borrowed `self.b` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed

Tags: rust

Here is a minimal subset of my code. My Rust compiler reports "cannot assign to `self.b` because it is borrowed. `self.b` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed"

```rust
struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn borrow_func(&self) -> &String {
        &self.a
    }

    fn test_func(&mut self) -> usize {
        let a = self.borrow_func();
        self.b = "".to_string();
        a.len()
    }
}
```

When I inline the function `borrow_func`, the error is omitted. However, the inlined code lacks readability. How can I fix the bug while **preserving the readability**?

Here is the inlined code:

```rust
struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn test_func(&mut self) -> usize {
        let a = &self.a;
        self.b = "".to_string();
        a.len()
    }
}
```

Comment: If `self.b` is not dependent to the `a` ( also `borrow_func`)  then you can just [switch the lines](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f5362962e583306daf4ebe24885bfd2) where you assign values to the `a` and `self.b`. This doesn't compile because compiler is not sure what you are doing in `borrow_func()` with `self`(there is a possibility that you can return a reference depends to `b`)

Comment: Could you clone the return value of borrow_func ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is just reorder the operations, The way you do the operations you have an inmmutable reference active and mutable reference active, so that's why the borrow checker throws the error about you have borrowed a variable.

I would recommend to study the rust lifetimes and trying to understand borrowing and ownership.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html

```rust
struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn borrow_func(&self) -> &String {
        &self.a
    }

    fn test_func(&mut self) -> usize {
        self.b = "".to_string();
        let a = self.borrow_func();
        a.len()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t: Test = Test {
        a: String::from("hola"),
        b: String::from("hello"),
    };

    println!("{}", t.test_func());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found that this code works

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Test {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn borrow_func(&self) -> &String {
        &self.a
    }

    fn test_func(&mut self) -> usize {
        let s = self.clone();
        let a = s.borrow_func();
        self.b = "".to_string();
        a.len()
    }
}
```

What is happening is that when `self.borrow_func()` is run it's passing `self` not `&self` because `self` is already a reference. To fix this we would instead do

```rust
self.clone().borrow_func();
```

But that gives us an error that it is a temporary value so to fix this we do

```rust
let s = self.clone();
s.borrow_func();
```

Comment: Cloning the whole `self` is wasteful (and not always possible). Instead, clone only the result of `borrow_func()`.